# Problem with Css & Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am having nested DIV's. Below is the Example.

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am calling a javascript function when we click on div one and div two.

Now the problem is sometimes the size of div two is large so that div one goes behind div two. Actually if i click div two i want to call both div one and div two. Since the javascript function name is dynamic, i am stuck.

Any idea how to call both js functions when we click div 2.

Comment: First of all change the ids of div. Id should never start with a number.

Comment: Some codes will be great to start the ball rolling.

Comment: Numbers in the IDs are just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the discussion [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) interesting. It gives good explanation and examples of event bubbling and propagation.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of div 2's click handler, you could call div 1's.

UPDATE:

What I meant is you could fire a click event on div 1 when div 2 is called.

Comment: The name of the function is dynamic. I mentioned it in the problem

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery you could do something like this

```
$('div2').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().click();
}
```